# Automatic assignment of Kafka partitions to Kafka consumers

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am creating a list of `Kafka` consumers as below:

```
public List<Consumer<String, String>> consumerPool(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties){
        consumerInstance = 10;
        List<Consumer<String, String>> consumerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int c = 0; c < consumerInstance; c++) {
            Consumer<String, String> consumer = consumerFactory(kafkaProperties).createConsumer();
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topic1"));
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
            consumerList.add(consumer);
        }

        return consumerList;
    }

public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
    }
```

I get the `KafkaProperties` set in the application config. I have set the `KafkaGroupID` to be "group1" in the `application.yml` so all the consumers belong to the same consumer group

The issue I am facing is the topics are not assigned to this consumers. I tested that using:

```
 Set<TopicPartition> partitionSet = consumer.assignment();
 partitionSet.forEach(topicPartition -> log.debug( "consumer:{}, Partition:{}", consumer.toString(), topicPartition.partition()));
```

Partition set is empty for all the consumers in the list.

I am able to assign the partition manually for each consumer using

```
TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("partition1", c);
consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(tp));
```

However I want this to be done dynamically instead of manually. The main reason is so that the partition is assigned automatically if a rebalance occurs.

Comment: The assignment won't actually happen until you `poll()` the consumer.

Comment: Here is my requirement, I need a list of consumers that are pre assigned to partitions. I read from Kafka on demand, when ever I have to read data from Kafka i check the list of consumers for free consumers and use a free consumer to read from Kafka.  
Is this possible without having to use poll, because if I poll()  the consumer it will read from Kafka which I don't want.

Comment: it doesn't work that way; you would have to use manual assignment, not group management.

Comment: Okay,  I tried using consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
But when I check the partitions, the partitions are still not assigned to the consumer. I have updated the question with the addition of poll. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: 10ms is probably much too little for the assignment to happen in time. The client is highly asynchronous.

Comment: If one of these consumers stopped working, would rebalance occur and the partition be assigned to another consumer?

Comment: Yes; it's a good idea to add a rebalance listener to the submit method so you get notification of assignment activity.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring all the consumers fall under same consumer group, kafka by default assigns each partition to each consumer. More information below:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding too. But it doesn’t seem to do so. When i check the consumers it does have the same groupID.